# How to enable second level cache in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jpa, orm

I need some pojo objects across my application so I want to know how to enable Second Level Cache. Until now by default First Level cache is enabled, I would also like to know what advantages and disadvantages of Second Level cache there are.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216630/hibernate-second-level-cache-net-sf-ehcache-hibernate-ehcacheprovider or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584585/hibernate-second-level-cache-example

Comment: possible duplicate-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358121/how-to-enable-second-level-cache-in-hibernate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

1. Set the following Hibernate properties:

   ```
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">ehcache</property>
   ```
2. Add an [ehcache.xml](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/integrations/hibernate) file in your classpath, containing the cache configuration entries:

   ```
    <cache name="com.mycompany.MyEntity"
       maxElementsInMemory="50"
       eternal="true"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="600"
       timeToLiveSeconds="600"
       diskPersistent="false"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"       
    />
   ```
3. Define the Caching type for each entity:

   ```
    @Entity
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    public class MyEntity {
            ...
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> Second level cache was introduced in hibernate 3.0
>
> When ever we are loading any object from the database,  then hibernate
>   verify whether that object is available in the local cache memory of
>   that particular session [ means first level cache ], if not available
>   then hibernate verify whether the object is available in global cache
>   or factory cache [ second level cache ], if not available then
>   hibernate will hit the database and loads the object from there, and
>   then first stores in the local cache of the session [ first level ]
>   then in the global cache [ second level cache ]
>
> When ever we are loading any object from the database,  then hibernate
>   verify whether that object is available in the local cache memory of
>   that particular session [ means first level cache ], if not available
>   then hibernate verify whether the object is available in global cache
>   or factory cache [ second level cache ], if not available then
>   hibernate will hit the database and loads the object from there, and
>   then first stores in the local cache of the session [ first level ]
>   then in the global cache [ second level cache ]

Answer (score 0):

JPA L2 cache is enabled, configured using the persistence property

**javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode**

which has values of NONE | ALL | ENABLE_SELECTIVE | DISABLE_SELECTIVE | UNSPECIFIED. Using this property is common across ALL valid JPA implementations.